# Setting form value using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

Here is a snip of my form i am using. I am using javascript to set the value of the dollars and cents to the 2 and 00 but it does not work. Can anyone correct this? Thank you

```
<select class="element select medium" id="element_8" name="element_8" onChange="update_txt()"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="First option" >First option</option>
        <option value="Second option" >Second option</option>
        <option value="Third option" >Third option</option>
</select>
        <input id="subtotal" name="subtotal" class="element text currency" size="10" value="" type="text" /> .      
        <label for="subtotal">Dollars</label>


        <input id="subtotalcents" name="subtotalcents" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" type="text" />
        <label for="subtotalcents">Cents</label>

        <script>function update_txt(){
                price = document.getElementById('element_8').value;
                document.getElementById('element_7').value = price;
                document.getElementById('element_7').focus();
                document.getElementbyId('subtotal').value ='2';
                document.getElementbyId('subtotalcents').value ='00';
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Where do you call the function?

Comment: on a dropdown menu onchange. The first bit of my javascript works but just the last two lines are giving me trouble.

Comment: Is the `<select>` closed somewhere in your original code?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You need to open a `span` *before* you close it. You aren't closing your `select`, which should happen after all of your options.

Comment: yes it is, should of included that

Comment: Is there any element with `id="element_7"`?

Comment: yes there is, didnt include that because the javascript works for it in this case

Comment: element_7 is not available there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `document.getElementById('subtotal').value ='2';`it is capital "B"

```
function update_txt(){
                price = document.getElementById('element_8').value;
                document.getElementById('element_7').value = price;
                document.getElementById('element_7').focus();
                document.getElementById('subtotal').value ='2';
                document.getElementById('subtotalcents').value ='00';
        }
```

**P.S:** There is no `element_7` in the code u provided, but hoping it is present in the actual code ur using.

Comment: Is element 7 is select or textbox

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>function update_txt(){
  debugger
                price = document.getElementById('element_8').value;
                document.getElementById('element_7').value = price;
                document.getElementById('element_7').focus();
                document.getElementById('subtotal').value ='2';
                document.getElementById('subtotalcents').value ='00';
        }
        </script>

</head>
<body>   

<select class="element select medium" id="element_8" name="element_8" onChange="update_txt()"> 
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="First option" >First option</option>
        <option value="Second option" >Second option</option>
        <option value="Third option" >Third option</option>
</select>
         <input id="element_7" name="element_7" class="element text currency" size="10" value="" type="text" /> .
        <input id="subtotal" name="subtotal" class="element text currency" size="10" value="" type="text" /> .      
        <label for="subtotal">Dollars</label>


        <input id="subtotalcents" name="subtotalcents" class="element text" size="2" maxlength="2" value="" type="text" />
        <label for="subtotalcents">Cents</label>

</body>
</html>
```